# Pass array values as parameter to function and create json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, loops

I have a scenario where I am passing an array of objects to a function in nodejs, but the same is failing with undefined error.

Here is what I have tried :

```
 var object = issues.issues //json data
 var outarr=[];
 for(var key in object){
   outarr.push(object[key].key) 
}
console.log(outarr) // array is formed like this : ['a','b','c','d','e']

for(var i =0; i<outarr.length;i++){  
jira.findIssue(outarr[i]) //here I am trying to pass the array objects into the loop one by one 
  .then(function(issue) {
    var issue_number = issue.key
    var ape = issue.fields.customfield_11442[0].value
    var description = issue.fields.summary
    var ice = issue.fields.customfield_15890[0].value
    var vice = issue.fields.customfield_15891.value
    var sor = issue.fields.labels
    if (sor.indexOf("testcng") > -1) {
      var val = 'yes'
} else {
  var val = 'yes'
}
var obj = {};
obj['ape_n'] = ape;
obj['description_n'] = description;
obj['ice_n'] = ice;
obj['vice_n'] = vice;
obj['sor_n'] = val;

var out = {}
var key = item;
out[key] = [];
out[key].push(obj);

console.log(out)
 } })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });


});
```

What I am trying to achieve : I want to pass the array values as a parameter which is required by `jira.findissue`(bassically passing the issue number) one by one and which should again fetch the values and give a combine json output.
How can I pass this array values one by one in this function and also run `jira.findissue` in loop.

Any help will be great !! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at the code in your question.
To be honest the code you wrote is messy and contains some simple syntax errors.

A good tip is to use a linter to avoid those mistakes.
More info about linters here: https://www.codereadability.com/what-are-javascript-linters/

To output all results in one array you have to define the array outside the scope of the loop.

I cleaned the code a bit up and use some es6 features. I don't know the context of the code but this is what I can make off it:

```
//map every value the key to outarr
let outarr = issues.issues.map( elm => elm.key);

//Output defined outside the scope of the loop
let output = [];

//looping outarr
outarr.forEach( el => {
    jira.findIssue(el).then(issue => {
        //creating the issue object
        let obj = {
            ape_n: issue.fields.customfield_11442[0].value,
            description_n: issue.fields.summary,
            ice_n: issue.fields.customfield_15890[0].value,
            vice_n: issue.fields.customfield_15891.value,
            sor_n: issue.fields.labels.indexOf("testcng") > -1 ? "yes" : "yes",
        };
        //pushing to the output
        output[issue.key] = obj;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});

//ouputing the output
console.log(output);
```

Some more info about es6 features: https://webapplog.com/es6/

Comment: This gives me an error as `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` for  `console.log(output)`

Comment: @Thomas can you put your whole code in this es6 linter (https://www.piliapp.com/syntax-check/es6/) and tell me if there are any errors? The code snippet I wrote has no syntax errors, maybe you forgot to close an if statement in the code above my snippet. Let me know what the results are! :)

Comment: I have put it in the above link and then it gives error 
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token` in same `console.log(output)`

Comment: You forgot to close something (maybe a if statement or a loop). Can you publish your whole code somewhere? Then i can take a look where your code goes wrong.

Comment: I resolved the error by closing the function scope, but now its giving me error when I am passing the array elements to the function.It says `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`

Comment: i want to pass array element one by one in the function to get result for example
first `'a'` element with same inverted comma or diuble inverted comma format should be passed to `jira.findIssue('a')` then it forms a array object , then next `'b'` should be passed to `jira.findIssue('b')` then it forms another array object .. like this I want total 5 array objects hold into the object in output at the end

Comment: I have published the code here https://jsfiddle.net/goua257f/

Comment: The variable output contains all objects created by the loop. You can fix the TypeError by checking of all the values inside variable obj exist.

Comment: My doubt is whether the outarray elements are getting passed to the function `jira.findIssue(el)` ?can you help me to understand that

Comment: because I am getting error as TypeError: `Cannot read property '0' of null` at `jira.findIssue.then.issue`

Comment: Yes, every element is passing one by one in the findIssue method. After every pass, the then method is called with the results. More about async in es6 here:(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) I also found an error on my part. output[issue.key].push(obj); has to be output[issue.key] = obj. I fixed the error in my answer. If you still have an error then one of the issue.fields don`t exist. You can test this by commenting out the whole let obj object and adding the whole issue to the output array. output[] = issue.

Comment: I have checked the same as you said to check the whole output. It comes as an empty array [], I am not sure why but the same thing works when I pass `jira.findIssue('a')`  manually

Comment: if the field value is not present can't I push NaN/null in that case to the final json array ? Is there a way to handle that